# Перенос первого элемента массива в конец

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать функцию, которая принимает массив чисел, например `[1,2,3,4,5]`, и переносит первый элемент массива в конец

Например можно засунуть первый элемент в конец, затем удалить первый элемент

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 1, arr[0]);
arr.shift();

console.log(arr);
```

подойдет ли такая функция?

Comment: помочь или сделать за вас?

Comment: [Массивы и как с ними работать](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: *"подойдет ли такая функия?"* --- если она делает то, что вам требовалось, то подойдёт.

Comment: Запустите вашу функцию и посмотрите на результат вы этого ожидали? А и вы не объявили функцию...

Comment: Какой результат в итоге должен получиться?

Answer (score 0):

Функции, которые перемещают первый элемент в конец массива.

Функции change и changeSp мутируют исходный объект, фукнция changeSl возвращает новый массив, без мутирования исходного

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function change(arr) {
  arr.push(arr[0])
  arr.shift()
  return arr
}

function changeSp(arr) {
  arr.push(arr.splice(0,1)[0]);
  return arr
}

function changeSl(arr) {
  const x = arr.slice(1,arr.length);
  x.push(arr[0])
  return x;
}

console.log(change(arr));
console.log(changeSp(arr));
console.log(changeSl(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать двумя способами:

1. Без мутации исходного массива

   ```js
   const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

   const rearrangeWithMutatiton = (array) => {
     array.push(array.shift());
     
     return array;
   }

   console.log('After rearrange without mutation', rearrangeWithMutatiton(arr).toString());
   console.log('Before rearrange without mutation', arr.toString());
   ```
2. С мутацией исходного массива

   ```js
   const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

   const rearrangeWithoutMutatiton = (array) => [...array.slice(1), array[0]];

   console.log('After rearrange with mutation', rearrangeWithoutMutatiton(arr).toString());
   console.log('Before rearrange with mutation', arr.toString());
   ```

Comment: На самом деле итог должен быть 3451

Comment: @АлексейШиманский С чего это?)

Comment: Мне так кажется))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уверен что, когда автор сказал "можно засунуть первый элемент в конец" имел ввиду продублировать первый в конце и только потом удалить первый элемент :)

Comment: та фиг его знат) он сам наверное не знает что имел в виду :D